# Custom macro for recall in keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, backpropagation, precision-recall

I am trying to create a custom macro for `recall = (recall of class1 + recall of class2)/2`. I came up with the following code but I am not sure how to calculate the true positive of class 0.

```py
def unweightedRecall():
    def recall(y_true, y_pred):
        # recall of class 1
        true_positives1 = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred * y_true, 0, 1)))
        possible_positives1 = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
        recall1 = true_positives1 / (possible_positives1 + K.epsilon())

        # --- get true positive of class 0 in true_positives0 here ---
        # Also, is there a cleaner way to get possible_positives0
        possible_positives0 = K.int_shape(y_true)[0] - possible_positives1
        recall0 = true_positives0 / (possible_positives0 + K.epsilon())
        return (recall0 + recall1)/2
    return recall
```

It seems I will have to use `Keras.backend.equal(x, y)`, but how do i create a tensor with shape `K.int_shape(y_true)[0]` and all values, say x?

---

Edit 1

Based on Marcin's comments, I wanted to create a custom metric based on callback in keras. While [browsing issues in Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5794), I came across the following code for f1 metric:

```py
class Metrics(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        predict = np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0]))
        targ = self.validation_data[1]
        self.f1s=f1(targ, predict)
        return
metrics = Metrics()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=[X_test,y_test], 
       verbose=1, callbacks=[metrics])
```

But how is the callback returning the accuracy? I wanted to implement `unweighted recall = (recall class1 + recall class2)/2`. I can think of the following code but would appreciate any help to complete it

```py
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
class Metrics(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        predict = np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0]))
        targ = self.validation_data[1]
        # --- what to store the result in?? ---
        self.XXXX=recall_score(targ, predict, average='macro')
        # we really dont need to return anything ??
        return
metrics = Metrics()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=[X_test,y_test], 
       verbose=1, callbacks=[metrics])
```

---

Edit 2: model:

```py
def createModelHelper(numNeurons=40, optimizer='adam'):
    inputLayer = Input(shape=(data.shape[1],))
    denseLayer1 = Dense(numNeurons)(inputLayer)
    outputLayer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(denseLayer1)
    model = Model(input=inputLayer, output=outputLayer)
    model.compile(loss=unweightedRecall, optimizer=optimizer)
    return model
```

Comment: There is a problem with computing `precision` and `recall` using `keras.metrics` and `keras.losses` `API. Remember - that the final value of loss or metric is a mean across every batch - but for `precision` and `recall` - a mean across the batches is not equal to the final metric value. I advise you to use `keras.callbacks` in order to compute appropriate values.

Comment: Thanks for that info! any pointer for the (custom) callback would be really appreciated! If it is easy to implement callback for (recall class1 + recall class2)/2, I would highly appreciate that in answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

keras version (with the mean problem).

Are your two classes actually only one dimension output (0 or 1)?

If so:

```
def recall(y_true, y_pred):
    # recall of class 1

    #do not use "round" here if you're going to use this as a loss function
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(y_pred) * y_true)
    possible_positives = K.sum(y_true)
    return true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())


def unweightedRecall(y_true, y_pred):
    return (recall(y_true,y_pred) + recall(1-y_true,1-y_pred))/2.
```

---

Now, if your two classes are actually a 2-element output:

```
def unweightedRecall(y_true, y_pred):
    return (recall(y_true[:,0],y_pred[:,0]) + recall(y_true[:,1],y_pred[:,1]))/2.
```

---

**Callback version**:

For the callback, you can use a `LambdaCallback`, and you manually print or store the results:

```
myCallBack = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=unweightedRecall)
stored_metrics = []

def unweightedRecall(epoch,logs):
    predict = model.predict(self.validation_data[0])
    targ = self.validation_data[1]

    result = (recall(targ,predict) + recall(1-targ,1-predict))/2. 
    print("recall for epoch " + str(epoch) + ": " + str(result))
    stored_metrics.append(result)
```

Where `recall` is a function using `np` instead of `K`. And `epsilon = np.finfo(float).eps` or `epsilon = np.finfo(np.float32).eps)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for that awesome answer!! How can the callback version be used for `metrics` parameter in model.compile? I am still not sure how the `metrics` parameter will associate the result to the metric.

Comment: The callback will not be a metric, that's why we created the `stored_metrics` list.

Comment: In the backprop stage, I want to use 'unweighted recall' to update the weights. How can I achieve that using the callback function? According to my understanding, I can use the first method to achieve this by updating the `metrics` to use `unweightedRecall`.

Comment: You must use a "loss" function. `loss = unweightedRecall` -- But this will only work with the keras function, not with the callback version. And you will have the problem mentioned by Marcin. But this doesn't seem to be a relevant problem. After all, almost all applications are divided in batches and treated as such.

Comment: thanks for the correction! that was really helpful :)

Comment: On using the loss function I get `ValueError: An operation has 'None' for gradient`. I see  `y_pred` is `<tf.Tensor 'dense_4/Sigmoid:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>`, but I doubt shape is an issue here as I still get the error if I do `y_pred = y_pred[:,0]` in `unweightedRecall`. The y_pred is output of sigmoid.

Comment: The model woks fine if I use `binary_crossentropy` loss instead. I have updated the question to include the model.

Comment: Hmmm, that's true.... it's the "round" function. It's not differentiable. Maybe you can use just `y_pred`. You won't get an exact recall, but it will work.