# Keras, Tensorflow - What is the meaning of K.epsilon when computing metrics

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics, epsilon

I am computing Recall and Accuracy for my model and I am wondering **why people add Keras.epsilon() to their variables** (examples found on stackoverflow : 
[Macro metrics (recall/F1...) for multiclass CNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261014/macro-metrics-recall-f1-for-multiclass-cnn)
or 
[How to calculate F1 Macro in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547402/how-to-calculate-f1-macro-in-keras/45305384#45305384) )

Thank you very much for your answer !

Kindly

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When there's a division operation taking place, it's often added to the denominator to prevent a divide by zero error. Epsilon is small value ([1e-07 in TensorFlow Core v2.2.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/epsilon)) that makes very little difference to the value of the denominator, but ensures that it isn't equal to exactly zero.

Answer (score 0):

epsilon: A small constant for numerical stability. This epsilon is "epsilon hat" in the Kingma and Ba paper (in the formula just before Section 2.1), not the epsilon in Algorithm 1 of the paper. Defaults to 1e-7
Source= [Click here](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/rmsprop/)